# Ubuntu Preseed Raid 1 with multiple partitions

Tags: raid, partition

I intend to create the following RAID 1:

```
Partition   Size         Filesystem
    /       20GB            ext4
    /boot   500MB           ext4
    swap    2GB         swap
   /backup  10GB            ext4
   /opt     all free size   ext4
```

I have triyng this configuration:

```
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-auto/method string raid
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
      multiraid ::                                         \
              10000 5000 20000 raid                        \
                      $primary{ } method{ raid }           \
              .                                            \
              200 512 500 raid                             \
                      method{ raid }                       \
              .                                            \
              2000 512 4000 raid                           \
                      method{ raid }                       \
              .                                            \
              10000 512 15000 raid                         \
                      method{ raid }                       \
              .                                            \
              10000 10000 1000000000 raid                  \
                      method{ raid }                       \
              .

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string \
    1 2 0 ext4 /                    \
          /dev/sda1#/dev/sdb1       \
    .                               \
    1 2 0 ext4 /boot                \
          /dev/sda2#/dev/sdb2       \
    .                               \
    1 2 0 swap                      \
          /dev/sda3#/dev/sdb3       \
    .                               \
    1 2 0 ext4 /backup              \
          /dev/sda5#/dev/sdb5       \
    .                               \
    1 2 0 ext4 /opt                 \
          /dev/sda6#/dev/sdb6       \
    .


d-i mdadm/boot_degraded boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

The setup displays a RAID configuration error and ask me to check the syslog file.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You reverted a spelling that was correct with your last edit and please provide the syslog